# Actualizar estado de componente con React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy trabajando con unos campos de selección que me envían los datos desde dos componentes hijos hasta un componente padre. Hasta ahí todo bien.
Recibo los datos y puedo imprimirlos por consola correctamente.
El problema comienza acá. Al momento en el cual quiero guardar el arreglo con los datos en una variable de estado e imprimo esta variable, sale como el estado no ha actualizado. Es decir, imprime un arreglo vacío.
Dejo el código para que puedan verlo.

```
const [ location, setLocation ] = useState([]);

const setLocationData = (data) => {

    setLocation(data);

    console.log(location); // Aquí imprime [] cuando debería imprimir el arreglo que contiene data

}
```

Comment: Podrías intentar cambiar de lugar el `console.log()` y ponerlo en otra parte del componente. Porque cuando se setea un estado, la actualización no es tan rápida como para que inmediatamente después puedas hacerle un `console.log()` y verlo ya actualizado.

Answer (score 2):

Las actualizaciones de Estado en react no son síncronas, son asíncronas.

Por esta razón, llamar a

```
setLocation(data);
```

e inmediatamente a

```
console.log(location);
```

No te va a entregar los resultados inmediatamente.

Para esto puedes esperar el siguiente render, o usar un useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(location); //esta línea se ejecuta la primera vez que se renderiza y en todos los cambios que location tenga, aqui siempre tendrás el ultimo valor de location
}, [location])
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el estado se actualiza en interfaz y al parecer después de un tipo render, si quieres ver que si se guardo en tu variable de estado puede realizar hacer un `console.log` después de tu `return`

```
const Example= () => {
    const [ location, setLocation ] = useState([]);
    return (
        <>
            {console.log('mi location', location)}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Listo, gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Verifico lo que me aconsejan y digo qué sucedió